# Wordpress category permalink 404

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I tried to update my site's permalink structure from the default to this: /%category%/%postname%/ but now the category links are redirecting to the not found page.

Strangely enough the permalinks for the custom post types are working fine.

I've been trying to find the solution for ours now, but I'm stuck. I think I'm missing something obvious here. Can anybody help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Leaving comment because I might be wrong, but maybe I could help you find the issue: Posts can have multiple categories so WordPress doesn't know which one you're actually querying. Your CPTs might not be using the "category" built-in taxonomy, therefore WordPress ignores that part of the permalink structure. This plugin might help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that should be the problem, because the category link itself is not working. So if I change the permalink structure, the index.php is loaded instead of the category.php, if I turn it back to default, it works again.

Comment: If you are using a local install you must make sure that the Apache Rewrite module is enabled. Sometimes its installed locally with that module commented out in the Apache httpd.conf file

The line in my file is
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

If there is a hash mark # at the front of that line, remove it and save the file. Or you can change it through your LAMP software's control panel.

after that you have to shut down and restart your LAMP installation after making that change.